# USA to Frankfurt (FRA), change airlines to Dresden and 2 separate tickets

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, international-travel, airport-terminals

I'm flying in May, USA to Frankfurt on Delta (Terminal 2, arrive 9am)then I need to take a Lufthansa flight (Terminal 1 at noon) to Dresden.
Is this enough time to get my luggage, go through customs, change terminals and security for the next flight?

Also, the return flight is on Sunday, DRS to FRA at 6:15am, arrive FRA at 7:20am, change airlines and terminal to a Delta 10:30 am flight back to the USA.

Is it enough time?

Comment: On Delta to and from Frankfurt and have to change to Lufthansa to get to Dresden, a separate round trip ticket for each airline.I have to claim luggage both times in Frankfurt. In i had Delta all the way I had to stop in Moscow and it was more expensive to route that way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In case you would miss the flight to Dresden, remember that you can also use the train from Frankfurt to Dresden. The flexible price oneway (maximum price for that trip) is 105 Euro, duration would be around 4:30 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Three hours would be enough time to complete this at any airport I have been through--if your flights run on time.

The only concern here is that, on two separate tickets, you will be responsible for the cost of a replacement ticket if your first flight is late and you miss your second one. This cost could be considerable on the way home if you needed to buy a new transatlantic ticket at the last minute.

For this reason, I wouldn't be comfortable with a gap that short between the flights.  Three hours is no problem, but it wouldn't take much of a delay for making your next flight to become a challenge.  Ultimately, it is up to you how much you are willing to risk buying a new ticket.

Note: travel insurance will typically not cover such a missed flight, either.

Comment: On the return it is the 1st flight out so I would hope it would be on time and then be able to claim luggage, exit, change terminals, ck bags , customs?

Comment: We all hope our flight is on time. You have a sufficient buffer if the flight is somewhat late, but there's always the possibility of a few hour delay, e.g. due to a maintenance issue. That's the risk you've taken on by booking separate tickets.

Answer (score 0):

You have three hours for both connections - that's tons of time.  And since you won't be clearing immigration and customs on the return trip (you'll do that at the first US airport at which you arrive), you'll have, in effect, even more spare time.

I wouldn't worry about this at all.

Comment: He does need to go through Schengen exit immigration in Frankfurt on the return trip, but as you say, there is plenty of time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Lufthansa is 1st flight out on return so it should be on time with 3 hrs to claim luggage, exit, change terminals, recheck luggage and security.  I certainly wouldn't want to buy a ticket that day though.